# Trying to print correct element corresponding to value

Tags: python

```
def main():
    rain = [] # empty list awaiting user input
    MONTH = ["January", "February"] # parallel to the rain?
    SIZE = 2 # array size
    getRain(rain,SIZE) # ask user to input each month rainfall amount
    highest = findHigh(rain, SIZE, MONTH)

    displayValues(SIZE, highest, rain)
    
# get input and add to list
def getRain(rain, SIZE):
    index = 0
    while (index <= SIZE - 1):
        print('Enter rainfall for month', index + 1)
        rainInput = int(input('Enter rainfall: '))
        rain.append(rainInput)
        index = index + 1

# finding the highest value in the array and printing the highest value with month
def findHigh(rain, SIZE, MONTH):
    highest = rain[0]
    index = 1
    while (index <= SIZE - 1):
        if (rain[index] > highest):
            highest = rain[index]
        else:
            index = index + 1
    print("The highest month is:", MONTH[index - 1])  # not too sure if I need this here
    return highest

# display the values
def displayValues(SIZE, highest, rain):
    print("--------------------------------")
    print("The highest value is:", highest)

# run code
main()
```

Hi, I am trying to figure out how to get it so then my output would print the right month in correlation to the amount of rainfall each month has (for example: january has 50 and february has 40)

> Output: The highest month is: January

I've tried making another condition thing or another module to try to check the values, but I cannot compare strings to int in the list.  I have also tried moving the print values but I feel like another module would be needed to find the right month unless I am just printing it in the wrong area

Comment: Perhaps what you want to do is use a dictionary to store you months and rain totals, not lists

Comment: @Chris as much as I want to and how dumb this may seem, the way how we're supposed to lay this out is to not use that as well to show the logic idk

Comment: Does findHigh have to return the highest value? Can it return the index that has the highest value?

Comment: @linus i have findHigh set to give out the highest value yes, but I am pretty sure I can have it return the index too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to change the rest of the code, you can modify findHigh to track and print the month with the highest value:

```
def findHigh(rain, SIZE, MONTH):
    highest = 0
    index = 1
    while (index <= SIZE - 1):
        if (rain[index] > rain[highest]):
            highest = index
        else:
            index = index + 1
    print("The highest month is:", MONTH[highest])  # not too sure if I need this here
    return rain[highest]
```

or slightly more pythonic:

```
def findHigh(rain, SIZE, MONTH):
    highest = 0
    for index in range(SIZE):
        if rain[index] > rain[highest]:
            highest = index
    print("The highest month is:", MONTH[highest])  # not too sure if I need this here
    return rain[highest]
```

It may be better to move both the prints to displayValues:

```
def main():
    rain = [] # empty list awaiting user input
    MONTH = ["January", "February"] # parallel to the rain?
    SIZE = 2 # array size
    getRain(rain,SIZE) # ask user to input each month rainfall amount
    highest = findHigh(rain, SIZE)

    displayValues(SIZE, highest, rain, MONTH)
    
# get input and add to list
def getRain(rain, SIZE):
    index = 0
    while (index <= SIZE - 1):
        print('Enter rainfall for month', index + 1)
        rainInput = int(input('Enter rainfall: '))
        rain.append(rainInput)
        index = index + 1

# finding the highest value in the array and printing the highest value with month
def findHigh(rain, SIZE):
    highest = 0
    for index in range(SIZE):
        if rain[index] > rain[highest]:
            highest = index
    return highest

# display the values
def displayValues(SIZE, highest, rain, MONTH):
    print("The highest month is:", MONTH[highest])  # not too sure if I need this here
    print("--------------------------------")
    print("The highest value is:", rain[highest])
```